# Cast from (NSDate) -> NSTimeInterval to unrelated type 'NSTimeInterval always fails

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the difference in the time from my iPad to my website, which are both local. Every thing works fine until I get to the line below, which should be taking the iPad time and subtracting the serverTime from it.

```
self.serverTimeOffSet = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(serverTime) as NSTimeInterval
```

I get the warning "Cast from (NSDate) -> NSTimeInterval to unrelated type 'NSTimeInterval always fails" and self.serverTimeOffset is never set.

```
var serverTimeOffSet: NSTimeInterval = 0.0

func setServerOffset(){
    var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    var url = NSURL(string: "http://someurl.com/time")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url!)
    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?
    request.HTTPMethod = "get"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response:NSURLResponse!, data:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            var dateString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
            dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            if let serverTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString){
                self.serverTimeOffSet = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(serverTime) as NSTimeInterval
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Thanks

Edit - Returned date from site:

```
2015-09-15T00:01:44.8530546-06:00
```

Comment: make sure date format returned by `JSON` and set in `DateFormatter` ("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") are same, otherwise it fails to convert to date.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the line "self.serverTimeOffSet = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(serverTime) as NSTimeInterval" and serverTime is a valid date.

Comment: @BryanH can you show your date string sample

Comment: @BryanH your format set for converting date is not same as returned by json. returned date has miliseconds while your format doesn't.

Comment: make sure `2015-09-15T00:01:44.8530546-06:00` and `DateFormat` should be identical. refere [Date Field symbol table here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns). I hope it would  be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this was stupid,

```
NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(serverTime)
```

not

```
NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(serverTime)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also format your date as follow:

```
let dateString = "2015-09-15T00:01:44.8530546-06:00"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSxxx"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
if let serverTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString){
   serverTime  // "Sep 15, 2015, 3:01 AM"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use lowercase "yyyy" for years. (*You* should know it :)

Comment: @MartinR I can't believe I didn't notice

Comment: Thanks for your help. My formatter was somehow working. My answer is below. I voted up your answer but cannot accept it.

Comment: @LeoDabus I guess `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:ss:mm.SSSSSSz` would be more specific. whats your thought?

Comment: @DipenPanchasara xxx is for extended hm, without Z see picture